# How to combine lambda and javascript forEach loops?

Tags: javascript, lambda, foreach, addeventlistener

Here's what I've tried and for some reason the event listeners are not getting called:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>Some sample text inside body
    <div id="log"></div>
    <script>
        var clipboardEventsHandler = ['beforecut', 'cut', 'beforecopy', 'copy', 'paste'].forEach((evt) => {
            document.addEventListener(evt, (e) => {
                log.innerHTML += ("-" + e.type + "-");
                log.innerHTML += (document.queryCommandSupported(e.type) ? "-" + e.type + " supported-" : "-" + e.type + " **not** supported-");
                log.innerHTML += (document.queryCommandEnabled(e.type) ? "-" + e.type + " enabled-" : "-" + e.type + " **not** enabled-");
                log.innerHTML += (document.queryCommandState(e.type) ? "-" + e.type " state:true-" : "-" + e.type + " state:false/null-");
                log.innerHTML += "<br>"
            })
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm suspecting that the type of `evt` parameter passed to addEventListener. I confirmed that its a string by logging `typeof evt` before passing it to `addEventListener`. And its says its `string`. But still the event listeners are not getting called when I do copy a portion of the text inside `body`. Can someone tell me what's that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You're aware that you're missing a plus sign, between `e.type " state:true-"`

Comment: Otherwise it seems fine -> https://jsfiddle.net/xc9rovk4/ ..... that's a typo !

Comment: Events are fired when that syntax issue is fixed. Always check console for errors :)

Comment: Please check your dev console by pressing `alt+cmd+J` on Mac or `alt+ctrl+J` on Windows/Linux in Chrome or inspect your page (on every modern browser)

Comment: you can find most of the issues in the TypeScript playground https://www.typescriptlang.org/play

Comment: Just curious: What's wrong with this question? Why down vote and votes to close the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First- you had a syntax error - missing `+` here:

```
e.type) ? "-" + e.type " state:true-"
                       ^----
```

Second - it's better access elements using `document.getElementById` and not directly by their id:

```
document.getElementById('log')
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>Some sample text inside body
    <div id="log"></div>
    <script>
        var log = document.getElementById('log');
        var clipboardEventsHandler = ['beforecut', 'cut', 'beforecopy', 'copy', 'paste'].forEach((evt) => {
            document.addEventListener(evt, (e) => {
                log.innerHTML += ("-" + e.type + "-");
                log.innerHTML += (document.queryCommandSupported(e.type) ? "-" + e.type + " supported-" : "-" + e.type + " **not** supported-");
                log.innerHTML += (document.queryCommandEnabled(e.type) ? "-" + e.type + " enabled-" : "-" + e.type + " **not** enabled-");
                log.innerHTML += (document.queryCommandState(e.type) ? "-" + e.type + " state:true-" : "-" + e.type + " state:false/null-");
                log.innerHTML += "<br>"
            })
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```